# Angular service single instance lazyload

Tags: angular

I know that it has been asked, but I can not find answer for my problem.

I created a lib that contains 1directive, 1 component and 1 service.

The lib is supposed to create anchors on the page.

User put the component in his app.component.html file.

Where user wants an anchor he have to use the directive.
When directive is loaded it notifies the service then on navigationEnd, service notifies the component (to display anchors labels)

Everything work fine when directives are used in a non-lazy loaded module.
While module is lazy loaded it seems that component and directve don't share the same instance of service.

I wish is clear enough
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't given code, but I'm guessing you're providing the service in a module, don't do that, use the `providedIn` option in the `Injectable` decorator:

```
@Inectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
```